# Link da âncora para direcionar para uma div não funciona

Tags: html, css, angular

Estou utilizando Angular 2+, estou tentando adicionar uma âncora que ao ser clicada vai me levar até a div destino, porém, quando clico na âncora, meu site é recarregado e adiciona o link #parallaxdiv depois do localhost... em vez de mover até o link.

Tentei algo como:

```
<a href="#parallaxdiv">Teste</a>

<div id="parallaxdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando:

**TS**

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<a (click)="scroll(target)"

<div #target>Your target</div>
```

Comment: Nossa top demais, a muito tempo procurava por isso rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Vale observar que para isso funcionar usando a solução marcada, é necessário ter um método com nome de scroll e que receba um parâmetro. No caso scroll(param) seria um exemplo de assinatura.

Da pra utilizar soluções prontas também como o [SmoothScroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smooth-scroll), que inclusive te possibilita configurar algumas outras funcionalidades, como por exemplo rolagem suave e definição do tempo de rolagem. Tem documentação simples e completa, mas de toda forma segue exemplo abaixo:

```
<!-- Script CDN para ancora -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll@15/dist/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>

<script>
  let scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
    speed: 300,
  speedAsDuration: true,
  <!-- History -->
    updateURL: true, <!-- Update the URL on scroll -->
    popstate: true <!-- Animate scrolling with the forward/backward browser buttons (requires updateURL to be true) -->

});
```

Feito isso é só utilizar normalmente no HTML conforme fez na descrição do problema:

```
<a href="#parallaxdiv">Teste</a>
<div id="parallaxdiv"></div>
```